# Possible to have a GUI in latex?

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to import an interactive GUI from an application such as MATLAB or RStudio so that the sliders and graph works on Latex?

Comment: your question is very unclear (although the answer is probably "no") what would you want the sliders in the interface to do, affect the latex typestting, or do you just mean include some kind of applet in the final PDF, in which case you are mostly asking about the capabilities of a PDF viewer rather than latex

Comment: @David Sorry I'll try to clarify, I have a GUI in Rstudio and another in MATLAB that when I adjust the sliders the graph changes on the plot. I was wondering was there anyway to bring this interface in. I have seen websites use graphs and I have assumed they wouldn't have the code for the sliders running in the background but rather an interactive image of sorts.

Comment: For Matlab a quick search found: https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37640-export-figure-to-3d-interactive-pdf So if you can export your graph in the right format (e.g., U3D) you can include them with `media9`.

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz Many thanks I'll take a look and that and hopefully find one for Rstudio also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no, depending on the actual requirements. You could use the `animate` package to create animations representing the change of a parameter. See the following example taken from https://www.uweziegenhagen.de/?p=3048

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5cm,paperheight=5.3cm,left=0cm,right=0cm,bottom=0cm,top=0.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{fom}{RGB}{0,153,139}

\newcommand{\dat}{0.7} % 0.67
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=last, controls, palindrome]{10}
\multiframe{70}{Ry=0.1+0.01}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=4cm,y=4cm]
\draw[line width=1pt,lightgray] (0,0) -- (1,1);
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (0,1) -- (0,0); 
\draw (0,0) -- (0.17,0.67); 
\draw (1,1) -- (0.83,\Ry); 

\draw [magenta,fill=magenta](0.17,0.67) circle (.5ex); 
\draw [fom,fill=fom](0.83,\Ry) circle (.5ex); 

\draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) .. controls (0.17,0.67) and (0.83,\Ry) .. (1,1);

\node[label={[label distance=0.0cm,text depth=-1ex,rotate=90]left:Fortschritt in \%}] at (-0.1,.8) {};
\node[label={[label distance=0.0cm,text depth=-1ex]right:Zeit-Achse}] at (0,-0.05) {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It creates an animated PDF with buttons to control the animation. More complex stuff is probably not possible, at least with pdflatex. Outside the *latex world there is for example th HilbertCurves app for iOS which has controls and is based on TeX. See their website at http://www.mathemaesthetics.com/HilbertCurves.html